# MVC ASP.NET - Getting jtable to call httpPost method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, jquery-jtable

I'm trying my hand at jTables with MVC 3, but have run into an issue.  When my page loads, I'm not getting any calls to my [HttpPost] method.  I think because of this, I keep getting the 'error connecting to database' message.

Can someone explain why my [HttpPost] method isn't getting called?  Here's the relevant code:

```
    <div id="CompetitionTable""></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jtable plugin
        $('#CompetitionTable').jtable({
            title: 'The Events List',
            paging: true, //Enable paging
            pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
            sorting: true, //Enable sorting
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sorting
            actions: {
                listAction: '@Url.Action("EventList", "CompetitionController")'
            },
            fields: {
                EventID: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                EventName: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '15%'
                },
                CompetitorEmail: {
                    title: 'Email address',
                    list: false
                },
                CompetitorName: {
                    title: 'Competitor',
                    width: '15%',
                },
                Score: {
                    title: 'Score',
                    width: '10%',
                }
            }
        });

        //Load list from server
        $('#CompetitionTable').jtable('load');
    });

</script>


 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EventList(int compId)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get data from database
                List<Event> events = Event.getEventsByCompetitionId(compId);

                //Return result to jTable
                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = events});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please can you show us the code how do you call it

Answer (score 0):

The way you call listAction is wrong. you should call it like this **'/CompetitionController/EventList'**

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC action waits for a parameter `(compId)`. But your lisAction does not provide that:

listAction: `'@Url.Action("EventList", "CompetitionController")'`

It must be something like that:

listAction: `'@Url.Action("EventList", "CompetitionController")compId=5'`

Probably, this table is populated dynamically for every competition and it's known on the server side. So, it must be something like:

listAction: `'@Url.Action("EventList", "CompetitionController")compId=@ViewBag.compId'`

Surely, you must set `compId` in the action of this view.